# How to figure out why some file was deleted from spring-boot repository?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have been updating my spring boot application from v2.2.1.RELEASE to v2.6.6 and I've noticed that one of configurations (HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration for instance) doesn't belong to spring boot repository any more. Please, explain me how to figure out why authors delete it and what should I use instead? And what should I do if I can't find such information in release notes?

P.S. Configurations also disappeared from other spring repositories (e.g. Spring Cloud Sleuth):

- TraceAutoConfiguration.class
- SleuthTagPropagationAutoConfiguration.class
- TraceWebServletAutoConfiguration.class
- SleuthLogAutoConfiguration.class

Comment: Could you have a look at the commit comments in the git repository?

Comment: I cloned repo to my PC and executed following command:

git log --full-history --oneline -1 -- spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.java

The output is: 61764389c2 Merge branch '2.3.x' into 2.4.x

Comment: I just had a look at [`HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.3.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.java) in the official repository and it seems it already got deprecated in version 2.2.0 and finally remove in 2.4.x (switching tags for that file). The Javadoc states: "@deprecated since 2.2.0 for removal in 2.4.0 in favor of HealthContributorAutoConfiguration". The situation is probably similar for the other classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you upgrade in stages, going from 2.2.x -> 2.3.x -> 2.4.x -> 2.5.x -> 2.6.x rather than jumping from 2.2 straight to 2.6, you'll see that the classes are deprecated for a period of time before they're removed. The deprecation message should point to a replacement. For example, `HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration` was [deprecated in 2.2.0 in favor of `HealthContributorAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/7ed64f0677709e460fbcbc19539487d8f7e59965/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.java#L32).

Comment: For Sleuth and Cloud in general you can check the wiki page for more information - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/